# Struts not working JBoss 7

Tags: java, jboss, struts

Moving a webapp from JBoss AS5 to AS7.  I'm able to successfully deploy the webapp - however, pages look weird.  Looks like my struts tags are not being recognized.  I look at my page source and inputs look like

```
<html:text  property="username" size="30" maxlength="30"/>
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" size="30" value="">
```

I'm guessing I have to include struts as a Dependency?  I try to do this with MANIFEST.MF.  My MANIFEST.MF exists in /src/main/resources/META-INF and looks like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.apache.log4j org.apache.struts
```

Doesn't seem to be working?  Is this correct?  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If your creating a module for the struts then you need to ensure module.xml is defined all the dependencies. Also ensure there is no any servlet-api.jar in your lib. You could give the dependency for the servlets API as follows.

```
 <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try place struts.jar to WEB-INF/lib/ directory into your web-app.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any jar file to jboss server as a global resource..
You need to create a module with that jar file and make it as global resource.
Need to add the following code in standalone.xml file for make it as global resource.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
    <global-modules>
         <module name="com.serverlib" slot="main"/>
    </global-modules>
</subsystem>
```

com.serverlib-The module name you have created which contain the jar file